# Chutzpah Test Adapter not displaying results

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest, chutzpah

I cannot get the Visual Studio 2012 Adapter to work. I'm only posting this question after several unsuccessful hours trying to get it to work. The .html file is being generated correctly but the results don't show. The context menu runner works - it displays results correctly in the Output window.

I notice when I look in the source of the generated .html file the references are to the jasmine files (and others) in the extensions directory. When I ran the page using chrome dev tools and stepped through the code there was an error because the JavaScript could not access the file path (which is what I would expect).

I'm planning a full JavaScript app for my next major project (node backend) and I would like to use Visual Studio for its testing tools and this would have been very useful but I don't want to spend any more time on this hence the reason for posting here. My question is similar to this one ...

[Chutzpah in Visual Studio 2012 Not Scanning HTML Test Harnesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717213/chutzpah-in-visual-studio-2012-not-scanning-html-test-harnesses)

The reason I've posted again is because I am not using an html page and I thought the other question was for something slightly different (although I may be wrong). I was following these instructions initially ...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meJ94rAN7P8

Comment: Could you file an issue on http://chutzpah.codeplex.com and attach a zip which contains a repro of your issue. Thanks!